# Necessary and essential features that java framework must include for testing,development and production

Tags: java, architecture, frameworks

May be this question broad and hard to answer at current moment
But,when i went through different frameworks emerging by one after another like

**Hadoop Distributed File System
HBase,
Hive,
Cassandra,
Hypertable,
Amazon S3,
BigTable,
DynamoDB,
MongoDB,
Redis,
Riak,
Neo4J,
Stripes,
 Wicket,
 Compojure,
 Conjure,
 Grails,
 JRoR,
 JSF,
 Lift,
 Netty,
 Noir,
 Play,
 Scalatra,
 Seam,
 Sitemesh,
 Spark,
 Spring MVC,
 Stripes,
 Struts,
 Tapestry,
 VRaptor,
 Vert.x,
 Stripes,
 Tapestry
 OpenXava**
It is always buzzing me.

Each framework has some unique features.Each one promises to solve some particular testing,development and production need   with respect to increasing no of users ,data expansion,distributed computing  and security ,performance  and many more .

But,many functionality is common on them .Striving for unique some functionality we have to shift from one framework to another As,a java developer i would like to have following features included in one framework
like

Out of box support for testing for unit and integration testing
Fast prototyping

Distributed multithreading,caching,logging ,session management ,moduaralization

Security extension

Framework extension

Easily integration with big data .

Distributed data computation

Asychronous operation

High performance

**I would like to know what other features others really want to have in one framework ?What others developer really want to have features  included in one framework .What are the necessary and essential featues that every framework must include .Please share yours idea.**

Answer (score 0):

The reason they differ is because there is no consensus on these matters. Depending on your background and expertise the answer will be different. Every project was started knowing full well what the alternatives were and not being content with them.

This question is useless I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think [XKCD](https://xkcd.com) describes it well (replace standard with framework):

[image: one standard to rule them all]

There is simply no way given an enough complex problem to solve it for all use cases and users.

Answer (score 0):

The key to understanding is not in how much common is there about all those frameworks but in that most of them cover only part of needs. For instance, Hadoop and Stripes do nothing in common. Only few frameworks claim they cover everything (Java EE and Spring in fact) but in reality they just try to collect several unrelated technologies under  one brand name.
The real domains are: presentation layer, data access layer and (arguably) something else.